# How to bucket data based on timestamps within a certain period or previous record?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data that I'm trying to bucket. Let's say the data has an user and timestamp. I want to define a session as any rows that has a timestamp within 10 minutes of the previous timestamp by user.

How would I go about this in SQL?

Example

```
+------+---------------------+---------+
| user |      timestamp      | session |
+------+---------------------+---------+
|    1 | 2021-05-09 15:12:52 |       1 |
|    1 | 2021-05-09 15:18:52 |       1 | within 10 min of previous timestamp
|    1 | 2021-05-09 15:32:52 |       2 | over 10 min, new session
|    2 | 2021-05-09 16:00:00 |       1 | different user
|    1 | 2021-05-09 17:00:00 |       3 | new session
|    1 | 2021-05-09 17:02:00 |       3 |
+------+---------------------+---------+
```

This will give me records within 10 minutes but how would I bucket them like above?

```
with cte as (
    select user,
        timestamp,
        lag(timestamp) over (partition by user order by timestamp) as last_timestamp
    from table
)
select *
from cte
where datediff(mm, last_timestamp, timestamp) <= 10
```

Comment: This is known as a *gaps-and-islands* problem, if you're looking for tutorials

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2021/08/t-sql-queries/bucketizing-date-and-time-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.  It's basically an edge problem.

[Working test case for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=21dfad0dee8b9ff559d99b01cc25062e)

**The SQL:**

```
with cte as (
    select user1
         , timestamp1
         , session1 AS session_expected
         , lag(timestamp1) over (partition by user1 order by timestamp1) as last_timestamp
         , CASE WHEN datediff(n, lag(timestamp1) over (partition by user1 order by timestamp1), timestamp1) <= 10 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS edge
      from table1
    )
select *, SUM(edge) OVER (PARTITION BY user1 ORDER BY timestamp1) AS session_actual
  from cte
 ORDER BY timestamp1
;
```

Additional suggestion, see `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` (thanks to @Charlieface):

```
with cte as (
    select user1
         , timestamp1
         , session1 AS session_expected
         , lag(timestamp1) over (partition by user1 order by timestamp1) as last_timestamp
         , CASE WHEN datediff(n, lag(timestamp1) over (partition by user1 order by timestamp1), timestamp1) <= 10 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS edge
      from table1
    )
select *
     , SUM(edge) OVER (PARTITION BY user1 ORDER BY timestamp1 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS session_actual
  from cte
 ORDER BY timestamp1
;
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (user1 int,   timestamp1 datetime, session1 int);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
  (    1 , '2021-05-09 15:12:52' ,       1 )
, (    1 , '2021-05-09 15:18:52' ,       1 ) -- within 10 min of previous timestamp
, (    1 , '2021-05-09 15:32:52' ,       2 ) -- over 10 min, new session
, (    2 , '2021-05-09 16:00:00' ,       1 ) -- different user
, (    1 , '2021-05-09 17:00:00' ,       3 ) -- new session
, (    1 , '2021-05-09 17:02:00' ,       3 )
;
```

Comment: You should add `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` to the `OVER` in case of duplicate timestamps. It's also more efficient

Comment: @Charlieface Interesting.  For the `SUM`?  I thought that was the default behavior.

Comment: `RANGE` not `ROWS` is the default, for some strange reason https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#important