# SQL Running Total Between Static and Variable Dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, cumulative-sum

I am trying to get a running total between the a static date and a variable date. Sales started in November of 2011 and I want to get the running total between November of 2011 and each month from then until the current month. Here is the code I currently have - does anyone know how to do this?

```sql
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(inside.order_date, 'YY-MM') AS "first_purchase_period",
  inside.loyalty_tier,
  SUM(inside.customers) OVER (PARTITION BY inside.order_date ORDER BY inside.order_date ROWS BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND CURRENT_ROW) AS "customers"
  AS "customers",
  SUM(inside.orders) AS "orders",
  SUM(inside.net_sales) AS "net_sales",
  SUM(inside.time_between_sales) AS "time_between_sales"
FROM (
  SELECT  customer_email,
          TRUNC(SCM.timestamp) AS "order_date",
          CASE
            WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) BETWEEN 0 AND 124.99 THEN 'no_tier'
            WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) BETWEEN 125 AND 198.99 THEN 'almost_vip'
            WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) BETWEEN 199 AND 749.99 THEN 'vip'
            WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) >= 750 THEN 'the_players_club'
            ELSE NULL
          END AS "loyalty_tier",
          COUNT(DISTINCT SCM.customer_email) AS "customers",
          COUNT(DISTINCT SCM.order_id) AS "orders",
          SUM(SCM.net_sales) AS "net_sales",
          DATEDIFF(day, MIN(SCM.timestamp),
            MAX(SCM.timestamp)) AS "time_between_sales"
  FROM {{ @public_fact_shopify_criquet_master AS SCM}}
  WHERE SCM.net_sales > 0
  GROUP BY customer_email, TRUNC(SCM.timestamp)
) AS inside
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(inside.order_date, 'YY-MM'), inside.loyalty_tier
```

**Here's the updated SQL with correction:**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(inside.order_date, 'YY-MM') AS "first_purchase_period"
     , inside.loyalty_tier
     , SUM(inside.customers) OVER (PARTITION BY inside.order_date ORDER BY inside.order_date ROWS BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND CURRENT_ROW) AS "customers"
     , SUM(inside.orders)             AS "orders"
     , SUM(inside.net_sales)          AS "net_sales"
     , SUM(inside.time_between_sales) AS "time_between_sales"
  FROM (
         SELECT customer_email
              , TRUNC(SCM.timestamp) AS "order_date"
              , CASE WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) BETWEEN   0 AND 124.99 THEN 'no_tier'
                     WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) BETWEEN 125 AND 198.99 THEN 'almost_vip'
                     WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) BETWEEN 199 AND 749.99 THEN 'vip'
                     WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) >= 750                 THEN 'the_players_club'
                     ELSE NULL
                 END AS "loyalty_tier"
              , COUNT(DISTINCT SCM.customer_email) AS "customers"
              , COUNT(DISTINCT SCM.order_id)       AS "orders"
              , SUM(SCM.net_sales)                 AS "net_sales"
              , DATEDIFF(day, MIN(SCM.timestamp), MAX(SCM.timestamp)) AS "time_between_sales"
           FROM {{ @public_fact_shopify_criquet_master AS SCM}}
          WHERE SCM.net_sales > 0
          GROUP BY customer_email
                 , TRUNC(SCM.timestamp)
     ) AS inside
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(inside.order_date, 'YY-MM'), inside.loyalty_tier
;
```

Comment: The running sum is simple enough.  So don't focus on that.  First get the monthly aggregate correct.  Until you have that, don't worry about the running sum.  Focus the question on one or the other.  Add the `CREATE TABLE` statement and just enough `INSERT` statements to show a problem.  Show your actual result and the expected result.  Be sure to focus just on the monthly aggregate, if that's not correct.

Comment: I'm really confused by your comment.

Comment: Start by providing a test case with actual data, minimal amount, just enough to show the behavior you don't understand.  This should be in the form of executable SQL that, when executed, produces your actual results.  Show your actual results and the expected result.  It's tough to know what specific problem you have without detail.

Comment: Note also that your SQL above has an error.  If that is just a typo in the question and not really part of your problem, you should clarify that you are (or are not) seeing an error when attempting to execute it.  I can correct the SQL for you, if you wish. **Question is updated.**

Comment: Yes I know it has an error that's why I'm on here. I don't know how to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: Also, your code correction came back with an error too.

Comment: Without a test case, I can not verify the entire statement.  I removed the obvious mistake, an extra `AS "customers"` fragment.  Since you had that syntax error, it wasn't clear you were asking about anything else.  If you can provide specific detail (as suggested above), the logic (or data) problem will likely be obvious.

Comment: How is my original question not a sufficient test case? I want data from the start date November of 2011 - each period which is monthly so November 2011 - January 2012 or November 2011 - November 2019 instead of the individual month or November 1st 2011 - November 30th 2011.

Comment: A test case is complete and executable and produces the behavior you want to correct.  This also assumes you explained the precise problem with your SQL, which you didn't.  I had to tell you about the error.  You should be telling me about the precise problems you see.  If you see an error, post that exact / complete error in the question.  For several reasons like this, the question is not complete.  A complete test case usually contains: 1) create table statements of interest, 2) insert statements to provide minimal required data, etc.

Comment: Here's an example of a reasonable test case, which I provided as part of an answer.  See the fiddle, and the "setup" section in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69421322/how-to-bucket-data-based-on-timestamps-within-a-certain-period-or-previous-recor/69421396#69421396

Comment: I'm telling you that I don't know how to run what I want to. I came out and said that from the front. This site is supposed to be to help people with questions not chastise them for formatting the question correctly.

Comment: The question doesn't contain clear requirements.  The purpose of the feedback was simply to help you understand what was missing, so that people can help you.  If you believe the question is complete and clear as is, that's fine.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query